# xsane scans only top of document while entire document is selected in preview

Tags: hp, scanner, hplip, xsane

I am using it with hplip software  and hp deskjet 2540.

When scanning lineart image: Only the top 5 cm or 2 inches is scanned while the full page is selected in preview.

Don't have this with greyscale or fullcolour scans, then I get the complete page

No errors seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the main window in Xsane, next to the scan button there is the dimension of the scanable area defined for your scanning device. Below that is the area you've selected in the preview window.  The area actually scanned will be the product of these 2 areas ie that bit that overlaps.  While you can change the preview area the area defined for your device is fixed by the manufacturer's device settings file.  This is a .drc text file which lives in ~/.sane/xsane.  I'm sure that you could edit it if you knew what you were doing but I don't.
To fix the problem I re-installed the latest version of HPLIP and set up the printer/scanner, and then reinstalled Xsane. Having done that ...

1)  In Xsane GUI go into Window/ShowAdvancedOptions and make the window as big as possible eg:
        Top L x = 0.0
        Top L y = 0.0
        Bottom R x = 21.59
        Bottom R x = 30.057

2)  From preferences, reload device settings eg:
        Hewlett-Packard:OfficeJet__6950.drc

If that doesn't cure the problem, contact the device supplier's support for the correct data set. If your device is supported by Xsane and you've installed the device properly before installing Xsane, then the correct file in ~/.sane/xsane/ and it can simply be loaded from the Preferences window.

I hope that helps
jg

Answer (score 1):

Delete the config with

```
rm -rf ~/.sane/xsane
```

For me the problem occured when I selected an area inside the preview window with the xsane logo, and closed it. I figured that, if I clicked a point at my scanned file, the selected area would be 0*0*0, forcing xsane to fail completely.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same prblem, I gave up using xsane and got the working done using the Simple Scan app.